# QGIS Python layerModified signal: how to find the id of modified feature

Tags: qgis, python, vector-layer

With this code on a vectorLayer v_layer:

```
QObject.connect(v_layer, SIGNAL("layerModified()"), self.interceptModify)
```

I can intercept when a geometry is changed, but how do i find which feature has been changed?

I need to find the modified feature id, but layerModified signal has not parameter

i tryed with

```
QObject.connect(v_layer, SIGNAL("geometryChanged(QgsFeatureId, QgsGeometry)"), self.interceptEditingModify)
```

no error, but the signal is not emitted by qgis

Comment: geometryChanged: The new Style `def test(fid, geometry):
... iface.activeLayer().geometryChanged.connect(test)` seems to work. Don't know how to write it old style.

Comment: Just don't use old style connects - there's absolutely no reason to choose them over the new style.

Comment: Please don't add "SOLVED:" to the topic title. Instead, use the `Answer` section below for a self-answer, for the benefit of future visitors: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/116101/is-it-ok-to-add-solved-to-the-title-of-a-question